# all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification.Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0

Tags: android, ocr, vision

Hi there i am making an app of extracting text from the image using OCR API of google. I am facing the problem in dependencies issue. I think there is a conflict in versions but i don't understand how to solve it.

I tried to update the google repository in SDK manager but still the problem has not solved.

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your dependencies

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
```

Comment: Hello @Radesh thank you the dependency issue is solved .....but in vision API now the problem is that isOperation() method is returning false what can be the possible reason?

Comment: if this problem solved please accept this answer and add another question and tag me and i will answer if i know problem

Comment: its my first time to use stack overflow can you please tell me who would i rank you because you helped me

Comment: there is a tick button close to my answer you can click on it

Comment: hi i have mentioned you in another post please reply me there @Radesh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513732/i-am-using-google-vision-ai-where-isopertional-is-returning-false-i-donot-know

Comment: kindly help me there Thank you so much. brother can you please share your facebook profile link with me?

Comment: sorry i don't have facebook account

Comment: can you please share any communication way? whatsapp etc?

Comment: radeshf.rf@gmail.com

Comment: thank you brother i have checked the link you sent me .........i tried to check if the disk-space is low but there is not the problem of disk-space. Is there any other way?