# I am using google vision ai where isOpertional() is returning false I donot know why because every thing is running fine

Tags: android, ocr, google-vision

Hi I am using Google vision OCR API for image to text extraction. The code is running there is no error in dependencies but still isOperational() method is returning false.

Comment: Oh nice question! check this out! https://stackoverflow.com/q/52855632/6401241

Comment: I never found an answer!

Comment: can you please share me your facebook link?